# How to programatically insert HTML in a Django template based on attributes in a model

Tags: python, django

In my view, I am receiving a list of `Event`s.  I want to display them on a timeline, where a header gets rendered for each new date, but multiple events on the same date at different times can get grouped under that single header.

In this scenario, I only want to display the header containing the date if the date is different than the `Event` that was rendered before it (I'm assuming the best way to iteratively render them is with something like `{% for event in events %}`)

How can I decide to render a certain html block only if `event.date` is different than the previously rendered `event.date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to go after is the ifchanged.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged